# Do nether strongholds only spawn within a certain radius?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft beta, normal strongholds only spawned within a certain distance of 0,0, so they would never appear in a world which was explored beyond that radius.

In Minecraft 1.0, do **nether strongholds** have a limit like this, or will they appear at any distance? Can you keep exploring and find unlimited nether strongholds?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nether Fortresses are closer to regular dungeons than they are to strongholds - that is to say, there's no set limit, and they spawn all over the place.

Here's a picture from AMIDST, a stronghold-finder tool with the Nether Fortress overlay active.

[image]

And here's a picture of another random portion of the same seed.

[image]

There's a definite pattern (though I don't know the exact code) to their position, and it extends in all directions with the map.

Comment: That's quite reassuring/disconcerting knowing you're surrounded by them at all times.

Comment: Any indication as to elevation for these?  Is there a "typical" elevation they're usually at?

Comment: @john They're pretty big vertically, and are guaranteed to be at least partly in the main nether cavern.